# How to capture the pid of a running process inside a script

Tags: linux, shell

I have been working with Linux shell scripts for a while. I came across a situation where the pid of a foreground process cannot be captured. Inside my shell script,

```
cfile="path/to/executable/C++/program"
$cfile
pid=$pidof c++ file
echo $pid > text file
```

But my c++ file contains a while loop which doesn't stop. So before reading the echo $$ line, my cpp file keeps running so I can't capture the pid of that c++ file into another file. 
I can capture and store if I run that as a background file using $!, but why doesn't it work for foreground process?
I know we can use `ps, pidof` commands to know the pid, but I want to store that pid to another file within a shell script.

Thanks

Comment: First, you don't use a command `pidof`, you are using a shell variable `pidof`. Second, you want to first run a program (`$cfile`) in the foreground, and then, **after the program has finished**, know it's pid. With other words: You want the PID of a process which does not exist anymore. I suggest that you modify your program so that it writes its PID to a file and read the file after the program has finished.

Comment: thanks..I have modified my program already.But I just wanted to know in anyway we can capture @user1934428

Comment: Capture the PID of a non-existing process? It's like taking a photograph of a non-existing animal. I don't think it can be done. Maybe you can search for information contained in /var/log; if Linux logs which processes it started, searching the respective log might reveal the process id. Maybe you can post a separate question on this subject, on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) or [Unix/Linux-Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: A related question is discussed [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/753550/unix-linux-command-to-see-finished-or-killed-processes)

Comment: you actually didn't get my question. My question was whether I can run the process continuously in foreground and simultaneously store it's pid in another file. Not the one you mentioned as "after the program has finished".@user1934428

Comment: But in you script, you explicitly express that you want to store the pid after your program has finished! If you want to do it while it is running, you have to do the storing of the pit at the same time that the program is running.

Comment: That was the code which I tried and I was asking for suggestions to store the pid of foreground process, which means I should run the while loop as well as store the pid! I hope you didn't read my requirement below the script @user1934428

Comment: Yes, and this means that you have to decide whether you want to store the pid while the process is still running, or somehow retrieve it in retrospect when the process does not exist anymore. If you want to do the former, you must doing the retrieval of the PID and the running of the process in parallel.

Comment: That was what I have been asking all this time. To store it simultaneously which mean in parallel.@user1934428

Comment: Then start the command with `&`, which allows you to retrieve the PID in `$!`.

Comment: Another possibility would be that you run `ps` from another terminal window and search for your program, but if there is more than one instance of the program running, it will be hard to tell which is which.